# How to find the HTML code of a incomplete page using FF addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Well, **document.body.innerHTML** works only when the page has `<body>...</body>` tag in the page. But if the page loading is interrupted due to any reason, the page will have `<body>` tag but no `</body>` tag. So, **document.body.innerHTML** will not work. How to get the HTML code of the page??

Comment: The browser will make a best-effort attempt at making sense of the markup. This includes adding missing closing tags, so _just_ a missing `</body>` tag isn't going to be a problem _at all._

Comment: Such prob occurs when load a big page with very low speed net connection (because of time out). You can trigger such error when you load a big page & immediately stopping the loading process.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to solve a problem that you shouldn't have.

Why is it a problem that the page load gets interrupted?

Comment: Because i know that if i use *document.body.innerHTML* then I'm sure that there is a chance (though very less) of getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each document has a root element, even if there is no body. So `document.documentElement.innerHTML` should always work.